# How to add CSS to a theme GTK

Tags: linux, gtk, themes, gtk3

I have been having issues adding more CSS an already pre-existing theme, no matter where I put the CSS most of it doesn't seem to apply, is there any way to prioritize my section of the CSS?

When I change the CSS that is already there instead of adding new CSS is applies properly...

The CSS also applies properly when putting it into the debugger

As an example I added this:

```
.titlebar {
    background-color:rgb(255,255,255);
    border:none;
    box-shadow:none;
}
```

To the bottom of one of my themes, but it never applies... And some things do apply if they don't already have one of the propeties I'm adding

Let's say I add a border to a button that usually doesn't have one then it works, but I can't change it's background color as it already has one... How do I circumvent/overwrite this?

Comment: Are you talking about OS themes? What distribution you are using? What display manager you are using? What paths you have attempted so far?

Comment: Yeah the OS GTK theme... using xfwm and Manjaro as my distro... As mentioned before I've simply tried to edit my gtk.css in my current theme... You might wanna read the question again :p

Comment: Yes, but there are many different .css files even with same name, so that is why I would like to know paths

Comment: /path/to/theme/gtk-3.0/gtk.css

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you want to change the appearance of (part of) a program of yours? I suggest you add the CSS locally in your program. I have experimented a bit with themes and, same as you, didn't get to a happy ending.

Thinking about it afterwards, I think changing the CSS 'locally' seems reasonable, because you avoid conflicts with updates... And if someone uses your code with another theme, it probably will still work.

```
style_provider = Gtk.CssProvider()
base_dir = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))
css_path = os.path.join(base_dir, 'input_paste.css')
style_provider.load_from_file(Gio.File.new_for_path("test_css_provider.css"))
Gtk.StyleContext.add_provider_for_screen(
    Gdk.Screen.get_default(),
    style_provider,
    Gtk.STYLE_PROVIDER_PRIORITY_APPLICATION
)
```

and the CSS file `test_css_provider.css` loaded by the previous code fragment:

```
#entry {
    border: 1px solid;
    padding: 10px 10px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    color: #D3DAE3;
    background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(30, 60, 200, 0.5));
}
```

I'm not an expert in things CSS, and generally don't like to change
program appearance, as this is a very tricky area (tastes and colors).

Comment: It’s more globally I want to change it... But as you said it doesn’t seem to be very easy... I really would rather not go and change the source code of all my apps then recompile it